# Proof Verification: Set of subsequential limits of a sequence is a closed set

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

Let $S$ be the set of all subsequential limits of a sequence {$P_n$}, and let $l$ be a limit point of $S$.

Let $S_{1} \subset S$ such that $\forall L \in S_{1}, d(L, l)<1$.

Since $l$ is a limit point of $S$, we can take $L_k \in S$ such that $d(L_k, l) < \frac{1}{k}$.

Construct a sequence {$x_k$} as follows:

For each of the $L_k$'s there is a subsequence of points in $S$ which converge to it. So we are guaranteed the existence of an $N$ such that $n\geq N \Rightarrow d(x_n, L_k) < d(L_k, L)$. Take $x_{n+1}$ as $x_k$.

Let $\epsilon \gt 0$, and let $N\in \mathbb{N}$ be the smallest possible such that $N > \frac{1}{\epsilon}$.

Then $d(x_n, L_n) \lt d(L_n, l) \lt \frac{1}{n} < \frac{1}{N} < \epsilon$.

So there is a subsequence {$x_k$} which converges to $l$. This implies that $l \in S$

$$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

Comment: "Is my proof correct?" is off topic (too broad, missing context). Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so.